# Как воспользоваться литералом, находящимся в пространстве имен

Tags: c++

Есть следующий пользовательский литерал

```
int operator "" exm(long double x)
    {
        return x * 2;
    }
```

Я его могу использовать следующим образом

```
6.exm;
```

Теперь литерал пихаю в пространство имен

```
namespace dx
{
    int operator "" exm(long double x)
    {
        return x * 2;
    }
}
```

Так, я не могу использовать его как раньше (`6.exm;`)
Вижу единственный выход только через `using namespace`

**Вопрос: Можно ли как-нибудь "на ходу" определить из какого пространства имен использовать литерал?**
(что-то вроде `6.dx::exm`, но такая запись не валидна)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте `using namespace dx;` в месте использования, так же как это делается у стандартных литералов, [например у `chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22h):

```
int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    auto day = 24h;
```

Comment: получается объявление `using namespace std::chrono_literals;` в main будет распространено на все его тело? Я так понимаю его можно ограничить {}. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Зачем этот ответ? Ведь такой подход ОП сам предложил в самом вопросе.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых пользовательский литерал является обычной функцией и может быть явно 
вызван из любого пространства имен соответствующим образом:

```
dx::operator ""_exm(6.0);
```

Во вторых, можно сделать имя этого литерала доступным в текущей области видимости. Этот вариант предпочтителен варианту с подтягиванием всего пространства имен, когда в нем находятся не только литералы.

```
using dx::operator ""_exm;
6.0_exm;
```

Comment: Действительно то что я хотел увидеть, я думал что по-другому (без using namespace) уже и нельзя. Спасибо Вам!